# What's the term for (tech-)companies discouraging integrating with other companies' ecosystem or through public protocols in general?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Especially when it causes said other companies to look bad?

Example:

- Google services and apps are (as far as I'm aware) available for all kinds of devices, Android, Apple, etc. For messaging and calling, it likewise uses either the existing public protocols or makes the technology available on any platform (e.g. regular "texting" and Duo).
- On the other hand, Apple has Facetime and iMessage, but these are exclusively produced for Apple products. Since iMessage seems integrated with normal texting, it may appear to iPhone users that Android users' phones are buggy or not working correctly, that they are missing features, and that "they should just get an iPhone".

I understand that this phenomenon is kind of a type of [Vendor lock-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in), but I feel it goes further because it is at the same time making competitors look bad. It's almost related to marketing, but the ones propagating the idea are the users, not the company. Is there a phrase, term or idiom in natural English or business or academic English that describes this? Or in any other language for that matter?

*Note*: I'm aware the same thing may be done by Google and other companies. My example is not meant to be a single argument to point out a guilty party or voice dissatisfaction with any company (I in fact wrote this question using an Apple device). The example mentioned is simply the one I'm confronted with the most in my personal daily life, even more so during today's COVID-19 pandemic when we rely on this technology to communicate with our friends and relative.

Comment: "The users" that you mention, and the sales people: _Maybe it's the **zealot fan base**. Or maybe the blue-clad agents really are inside our heads when we walk away from the Bar._ from https://gizmodo.com/how-to-be-a-genius-this-is-apples-secret-employee-trai-5938323

Comment: It seems as though the term "walled garden," as applied to tech companies, might be what you have in mind here.